# SEM: Normal-theory Maximum Likelihood fitting function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I took a few courses where model estimation via Maximum Likelihood in Structural Equation Modeling was discussed. There was one definition of the normal-theory ML fitting function that I also found in classic literature (like [Bollen, 1989](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118619179)):

$ \hat{F}_{ML} = \ln|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\boldsymbol{\theta})| + tr[\mathbf{S} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\boldsymbol{\theta})^{-1}] - \ln|\mathbf{S}|- p $

where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is the model-implied covariance matrix, $\mathbf{S}$ is the observed sample covariance matrix and $p$ is the number of manifest variables.
Bollen (1989) demonstrates that when $\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} = \mathbf{S}$ (and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is substituted with $\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}$), $\hat{F}_{ML}$ is zero, thus representing perfect fit.

However, in the course I saw a specification like this:

$ \hat{F}_{ML} = \ln|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\boldsymbol{\theta})| + tr[\mathbf{S} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\boldsymbol{\theta})^{-1}] - \ln|\mathbf{S}|- p + [\mathbf{m}-\boldsymbol{\mu}(\boldsymbol{\theta})]'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}[\mathbf{m}-\boldsymbol{\mu}(\boldsymbol{\theta})] $

where it seems like the meanstructure is added to the fitting function as well, where $\mathbf{m}$ is the observed mean vector and $\boldsymbol{\mu}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is the model-implied mean vector.

My assumption why there are these two different definitions is that in classical CFA (and many other types of more general SEM) the meanstructure is saturated and model misfit could not come from the meanstructure. This would mean that $[\mathbf{m}-\boldsymbol{\mu}(\boldsymbol{\theta})]$ is zero because $\mathbf{m}=\boldsymbol{\mu}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ and the additional term would disappear. However, I could not find any literature that confirms this, so if anyone knows where the second (more general) specification is from or could explain it in more detail, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second specification adds the model implied means. In the  Lisrel v7 manual (by Joreskog and Sorbom) these were called the full model and the extended Lisrel model.

In a lot of CFA (and SEM) you don't try to model the means and intercepts so we just ignore this part. The mean/intercept of every latent variable is constrained to zero, and the mean/intercept of every measured variable is free. As you say, the mean structure then adds nothing so we can ignore it. I don't recall if Bollen's book mentions means anywhere - most introductory books don't.

Edit: The preview of the Lisrel user guide (version 8) has the description of the extended lisrel model on page 297: https://www.google.com/books/edition/LISREL_8/9AC-s50RjacC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=extended

Answer (score 0):

Because any covariance is symmetric ( the absolute value operator will produce this when used to calculate a covariance in a square matrix for example ), there will always be a positive and a negative solution possible, but because you are looking for a real-valued result and not a negative one, the negative is thrown out or set to zero and only the fitting positive value used.